# How to export Windows System and Application event log?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log

Using the [`EvtExportLog` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtexportlog), I currently fail to specify a correct value for the `Path` and/or `Query` parameter.

My goal is to export the local **Application** and **System** event log.

I've tried:

```
EvtExportLog(
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    "Application", 
    "*", 
    "C:\\SomePath\\Application.evtx", 
    EventExportLogFlags.LogFilePath);
```

with the following P/Invoke definition:

```
[Flags]
private enum EventExportLogFlags
{
    ChannelPath = 1,
    LogFilePath = 2,
    TolerateQueryErrors = 0x1000
};

[DllImport(@"wevtapi.dll", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
    SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool EvtExportLog(
    IntPtr sessionHandle,
    string path,
    string query,
    string targetPath,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] EventExportLogFlags flags);
```

Unfortunately the function returns `false` and a last error code of 2 ([ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)).

**My question:**

What to put in the `Path` and `Query` parameters to export the local Application and System event log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question:

My `Path` and `Query` was actually correct. What was wrong, was the `Flags` parameter.

Instead of specifying the `EventExportLogFlags.LogFilePath` parameter, I had to specify the `EventExportLogFlags.ChannelPath` parameter.

Then the export succeeds:

```
EvtExportLog(
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    "Application", 
    "*", 
    "C:\\SomePath\\Application.evtx", 
    EventExportLogFlags.ChannelPath); // <-- HERE!
```